# Reordering validation in icefaces ace:tree

Tags: validation, jsf, tree, icefaces

I'm trying to use reordering feature of ace:tree component in icefaces. I have 3 types of nodes in my tree. My goal is to put some constraints on the tree.

Let's say i have node types A, B and C. 
A is the root node
A can have only B type children
B can have children of type B or C

I want to block reordering when these constraints are not met. How one would apply such validation in ace:tree?

EDIT1
I forgot to mention that i have my validation implemented but what's not working is validation when using drag and drop feature (view updates to invalid state, model stays as it was when doing invalid operation) I need a clever way to refresh my view.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, without knowing how your code looks like, you have probably built your tree structure using nodes like 
[this one](http://sventon.icesoft.org/svn/repos/repo/show/icefaces3/trunk/icefaces/samples/showcase/showcase/src/main/java/org/icefaces/samples/showcase/example/ace/tree/LocationNodeImpl.java;jsessionid=1A2E5BEA1DBAE0827B627429FCC9C030?revision=30725).
Therefore, you can constrain the data model (the parent nodes from the list) to accept only the values that you want.
You can signal to the user that an operation is not permitted using FacesMessage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do what you said. I validate the model input and not let unwanted data in. But the problem is the view is still wrong and I can't find a way to repaint it.

Comment: I do not understand your issue. Normally, if you change the data model, the UI should automatically be updated (a consequence of using ace components). So you are saying that the FacesMessage is not displayed, or what?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this happens when I'm using the drag and drop feature. When i drag a node to a place where it's not allowed by my model the view changes but my model does not becouse of the validation. And so the view is wrong at this point. I'd like to refresh it somehow.